# use function length for method overloading

Tags: javascript

I got this code from here:
http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#90

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn){ 
          // Save a reference to the old method 
          var old = object[ name ]; 

          // Overwrite the method with our new one 
          object[ name ] = function(){ 
            // Check the number of incoming arguments, 
            // compared to our overloaded function 
            if ( fn.length == arguments.length ) 
              // If there was a match, run the function 
              return fn.apply( this, arguments ); 

            // Otherwise, fallback to the old method 
            else if ( typeof old === "function" ) 
              return old.apply( this, arguments ); 
          }; 
        } 

        function Ninjas(){ 
          var ninjas = [ "Dean Edwards", "Sam Stephenson", "Alex Russell" ]; 
          addMethod(this, "find", function(){ 
            return ninjas; 
          }); 
          addMethod(this, "find", function(name){ 
            var ret = []; 
            for ( var i = 0; i < ninjas.length; i++ ) 
              if ( ninjas[i].indexOf(name) == 0 ) 
                ret.push( ninjas[i] ); 
            return ret; 
          }); 
          addMethod(this, "find", function(first, last){ 
            var ret = []; 
            for ( var i = 0; i < ninjas.length; i++ ) 
              if ( ninjas[i] == (first + " " + last) ) 
                ret.push( ninjas[i] ); 
            return ret; 
          }); 
        } 

        var ninjas = new Ninjas(); 
        assert( ninjas.find().length == 3, "Finds all ninjas" ); 
        assert( ninjas.find("Sam").length == 1, "Finds ninjas by first name" ); 
        assert( ninjas.find("Dean", "Edwards").length == 1, "Finds ninjas by first and last name" ); 
        assert( ninjas.find("Alex", "X", "Russell") == null, "Does nothing" );
```

I understand 1)function length is the length of arguments in definition and 2) arguments refer to array of variables for outer function.

but What does the **arguments** refer to in the addMethod()? I think it is 0 and the addMethod won't work. But it works. Can you help me understand addMethod?

Comment: Note that *arguments* is not an array. It is an [object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) that has the values passed to the function accessible by index based on the order they are passed and a *length* property that is the number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

[`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) indicates the number of parameters expected by the function and it is 3 in the case of `addMethod`. And [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) refers to the array of arguments which are passed to `addMethod`.

So, the `addMethod` function checks if the expected number of parameters match the actual number of parameters passed.

1. If they match, it simply executes the third parameter (which is expected to be a function).
2. Otherwise, it executes the function by the name referred by the second parameter.

Comment: fn.length is the number of variables in function definition and it is not always 3 in this case. Is it right?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu If the function defn has 3 variables, then it will be 3 always

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is build-in JavaScript Array-like object which every `function` implicitly has. It contains array of passed arguments to the function. However `arguments` object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array, but does not have any Array properties except `length`.

Comment: in the code it says "arguments.length", so arguments has length property, right?

Comment: Do you know the arguments is for which function in this case? It is the part that I am confused about.